# How to open documents (e.g. PDF) in Cordova App for Windows Phone 8 platform?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, cordova-plugins

I couldn't find a way to open a default "Open with..." context menu.

The document data is stored as a datastring in JavaScript.

My only approach is trying to save the file locally and open it over cordova-plugin-file-opener2.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I prefer to use the default apps to open PDF files. If you want to create a desktop like context menu, you must create the CSS to do that and use something like [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to create a PDF reader.

**EDIT:** To open the default app you should open the Internet Explorer an use the local URI of the file.

You have to use the LaunchFileAsync method of Launcher class. Example:

```
// Access the file.
StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");

// Launch the pdf file.
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

Comment: And how do you open data with default apps using JavaScript?